# Casting contents of an indexer's returned collection?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, type-conversion

I have a table/row/column data structure setup. There is a string-based indexer in the DtaTable class to return DtaRows, and another on the DtaRow class to return DtaColumns. So you can write things like...

```
return theTables["tablename"]["rowidentifier"]["columnname"];
```

In actuality, the objects inside the tables are not DtaRows, but one of about three dozen subclasses, like `InflationRow` and `CurrencyRow`. Each table contains only objects of those types, so for instance...

theTables["Inflations"]["General"];

always returns an `InflationRow`.

Now to make this easier to access from C#, I have a bunch of methods at a higher level like...

```
public DtaTable Inflations { get {return pTables["Inflations"];} }
```

Now the problem I'd like to solve is that when someone calls one of these methods, they don't get an InflationRow, because DtaTable has DtaRows. So for instance...

```
MyInfRow = Inflations["General"];
```

returns a DtaRow. So I have to cast all the time...

```
MyInfRow = (InflationRow)Inflations["General"];
```

I want to get rid of all the casting.

The only solution I have found so far is to make 36 new subclasses of the table object, each overriding the indexer return type. This seems worse than the casting.

Is there some simpler way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of the casting because its annoying or because you don't want casting?

Comment: Because the code in question is being converted from VB where there was no casing because they have multiple indexers (essentially) so they had ones that returned the proper class. So if I have to use casting, I have 150000+ lines of code to add a cast to.

Answer (score 1):

It you know that callers are only primarily going to use another indexer, you can introduce a generic class providing that:

```
public class SpecializedTable<T> 
{
    private readonly DtaTable table;

    // Just in case anyone really wants this
    public DtaTable Table { get; }

    public SpecializedTable(DtaTable table)
    {
        this.table = table;
    }

    public T this[string row] { get { return (T) (object) table[row]; } }
}
```

As an aside, these `DtaTable` etc names feel annoying unpronounceable / easily confusable with the .NET `DataTable` classes. If you're in a position to rename them, I'd suggest you do so.

Then your `Inflations` property can be:

```
public SpecializedTable<InflationRow> Inflations
{ 
    get
    {
        return new SpecializedTable<InflationRow>(pTables["Inflations"]);
    }
}
```

You may want to cache this to avoid creating a new object each time you call the property though.

At that point, this code: `Inflations["General"]` will perform the cast appropriately for you.

Comment: Could you please explain why do you cast table[row] to object before casting to target type?

Comment: @CodingFeles: Casting with generic types is complicated - various things aren't allowed unless you cast to `object` first. It's *possible* that it's not required here, but I think it is.

Comment: Oh I think this is precisely the sort of thing I was looking for. Let me try this!

Comment: @JonSkeet What is the "DtaView"? I'm not sure I understand what that code is for? And there's a note at the top about using another indexer... that is not always the case. Many of these will stop with something like `Inflations["General"].somePropertyOnTheInflation` Is that OK, I don't have it compiling yet.

Comment: Oh wait, I see what's happening here. We're creating a second private object to wrap the underlying DtaTable? I'm not sure that works in this case... let me ponder.

Comment: @Maury: Sorry about DtaView - fixed. I changed my mind about the name. Why wouldn't the wrapping work here?

Comment: @JonSkeet It might work just fine but we do call these methods about 50 to 100000 times on an average run, so I'm concerned about hiding the underlying object in a second object. I just have to try it and see what happens - it would be cool if you could subclass the T as a DtaTable, but I think that defeats the purpose?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz: That's why I said you might want to cache the instance of the wrapper class - but you may be surprised at how efficient the GC is. (You *could* make it a struct if you really wanted.) I'm not sure what you mean by "subclass the T as a DtaTable"...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90563/discussion-between-maury-markowitz-and-jon-skeet).

Comment: Ok I'm implementing this now - one question. Perhaps I don't need this any more, but I made the return type an interface (perhaps for COM? I don't even remember why). Can I have the `this` have its return type also conform to the protocol? I tried a few obvious things but I can't seem to get the syntax (assuming it even works). Or perhaps the correct solution is to have the interface not export DtaRow, but something else?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz: I don't understand what you mean, I'm afraid - I can't picture what you're trying. I suggest you ask a new question with an example.

Comment: I think it's working! I did use a cache for each collection. There's only 36 of them so it doesn't seem egregious. Funny though, this is a non-problem under VB because you can have multiple indexers, and have them return whatever you want. I find it surprising this isn't in c# as well.

Answer (score -1):

Use `as` instead of direct cast. If casting is valid it will return the instance, otherwise it will stay as NULL.

```
public MyInfRow Inflations { get {return pTables["Inflations"] as MyInfRow } }
```

Comment: I don't think you've read the question properly - `Inflations` doesn't return an `InflationRow`, but it returns something whose *indexer* should return an `InflationRow`. The OP hasn't complained that there are casting issues that cause exceptions.

Comment: I thought he was having issues with casting, my mistake.